# check if key exists in Icollection using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, namespaces

Is there an easy way to check if a particular key exists in a keyvalue collection without ofcourse looping through the collection ?

Like an alternative for  Dictionary.ContainsKey() ?

```
 Public mod_filters As ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

this is my collection . I need to find if a particular key exists in the collection. If it doesnt then add that key and a corresponding value.

Comment: why aren't you using a Dictionary?

Comment: @w0lf I had to read through and write to the dictionary quite often and i thought looping through a collection was simpler than using a dictionary.

Comment: but with a Dictionary, you would not have to loop thru the items to see if it exists.

Comment: Dictionary contains code to optimise finding keys. If you need an optimum way of finding a key, you probably either need a dictionary, or you need to recreate the code in the Dictionary class.

Comment: @Plutonix thats true. and that is what i want to achieve in the collection

Comment: You can take a look at the [Dictionary<TKey><TValue> class in Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0) to see how Microsoft did it.

Comment: So you want to check if a key exists in an `ICollection<T>`? As always, use LINQ: `Dim containsFoo = mod_filters.Any(Function(pair) pair.Key = "foo")`

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå hey thanks that worked :)

Comment: Advice to check [KeyedCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx). It is can be good tip for your purpose